# Calling execv() failed

Tags: c, linux

**Code:**

```c
static void child() {
    char* args[] = {"/bin/echo", "Hello World!", NULL};
    printf("I'm child! My PID is %d.\n", getpid());
    fflush(stdout);
    execv("/bin/echo", args); // !!
    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "execv() failed");
}

static void parent(__pid_t pid_c) {
    printf("I'm parent! My PID is %d and my child's PID is %d.\n", getpid(), pid_c);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main() {
    __pid_t ret;
    ret = fork();

    if (ret == -1) {
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "fork() failed");
    } else if (ret == 0) {
        child();
    } else {
        parent(ret);
    }

    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Shouldn't reach here");
}
```

**Result:**

```
I'm parent! My PID is 4543 and my child's PID is 4544.
I'm child! My PID is 4544.
```

In above code, I want to replace `child` process to `/bin/echo` process, but `echo` doesn't work. More precisely, calling `execv()` is failed.

What is the problem?

Comment: I don't see "execv() failed" in your output.  Looks like that `err()` is not called.  Why do you think execv is failing?

Comment: What is __pid_t? POSIX fork returns pid_t

Comment: Your code works for me, after I change `__pid_t` to the correct `pid_t`.  What environment are you running this in?  Since the child process is a, well, child process, the parent returns to its caller before the child has necessarily finished.  For example, when I run the program, I see "Hello World!" come out *after" my next shell prompt.  If you're running this under some kind of an IDE, the child's output might be getting lost after the parent finishes.  You might try putting a call to `sleep(10)` in `parent()` (between the calls to `printf` and `exit`, that is).

Comment: the parent process needs to call `wait()` or `waitpid()` so it waits until the child process has completed.  The parent exiting first is a well known method to produce a 'zombie'  (although modern OSs actually attach the child to the `init` process.  As it is, the parent is exiting first in the posted code, which results in the child never performing the `exec*()` function and ...,`

Comment: besides the missing `wait()` statement, the posted code is also missing: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <err.h>`  are you expecting us to guess as to which header files your code actually included?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I've changed `__pid_t` to `pid_t`. I didn't know that because it is included in `sys/types.h`.

Comment: The usage is as in the manual pages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly waits for the child process to complete
4. contains the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <err.h>

static void child() {
    char* args[] = {"/bin/echo", "Hello World!", NULL};
    printf("I'm child! My PID is %d.\n", getpid());
    fflush(stdout);
    execv( args[0], args); 
    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "execv() failed");
}

static void parent(__pid_t pid_c) {
    printf("I'm parent! My PID is %d and my child's PID is %d.\n", getpid(), pid_c);
    wait( NULL );
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main() {
    __pid_t ret;
    ret = fork();

    if (ret == -1) {
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "fork() failed");
    } else if (ret == 0) {
        child();
    } else {
        parent(ret);
    }

    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Shouldn't reach here");
}
```

the resulting output is:

```
I'm parent! My PID is 31293 and my child's PID is 31294.
I'm child! My PID is 31294.
Hello World!
```

Comment: Thanks. `wait(NULL);` seems to be important.

Comment: @nblizz it very likely was so that the hello world was overwritten by your prompt or so...